# While loop missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

```
simulate_queue<- function(open_time, rate, low, high){
i<-1
j<-1
a<-rexp(1,rate)
b<-runif(1,low,high)
c<-a+b
d<-a + rexp(1,rate)
e<-c()
 while (d <= open_time) {
  a[i+1]<- d
  if (a[i+1] < c[i]){
  c[i+1]<-c[i]+b
  b<- runif(1,low,high)
}
else c[i+1]<-a[i+1]+b
e[i]<-( while(d <= open_time){
  if (c[j] < a[i+1]) {sum(c[j]< a[i])
   i <- i+1
    }
  else if (c[j] > a[i+1]) {0
  j <- j+1
  }
  else 0
 }
  )
  i<-i+1
  d <- a[i] + rexp(1,rate)
 }

 L <- list(arrival_times=a,queue_lengths=e,departure_times=c)
 L
}
```

I don't know why there is an error message
Error in if (c[j] < a[i + 1]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Please help me..

Comment: You probably have an `NA` value in your input data somewhere

Comment: I input simulate_queue(10,0.7,1,2)

Comment: All I know is that your error can be replicated with `if (NA < 2) "yay"` - somehow you're ending up with a comparison in the `if (c[j] < a[i+1])` line that doesn't work. Try `debug(simulate_queue)` and walk through your program.